# How to add multiple images in a page

Tags: images, themes, gallery, customization

I am developing a WordPress Theme and I've got stuck in a point. What I want to do is to add a box at the right of page editor so the admin of the site can add multiple images on the fly in this concrete page. I've found that WooCommerce has this box enabled at the product creation editor. Do anybody know how can I create this box and how to access the uploaded images from the frontend?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy task and I don't think it can be covered as a forum answer.

You need to make sure that you know how to add metaboxes at post types and then how to use the media uploader of wordpress, plus plenty of javascript...

If you are not familiar with metaboxes and the uploader it will take you some time to get comfortable with them. In that case you could leave it in the choice of your theme's users to use a plugin for this functionality. There are several plugins for this, free and premium.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the metaboxes, so you can call them with a "prefix" and then call the $prefix in the_loop or something.

Comment: Please explain yourself a bit more. It's hard to follow what you are explaining. You could add an example (in code) to illustrate what you are talking about.